# XCode Build Artifacts Showing Up Elsewhere

Tags: ios, xcode

I have an iOS project that sat in `development` directory for years. Didn't think much of it. While doing some cleanup I added a `development/mobile/` directory and moved the project into there.

The next time I built, I noticed a `build` directory in `development/build`. This was causing all kinds of weirdness where changes to my code weren't be run on the target device, breakpoints weren't hitting, etc. In hindsight I see why but I'm surprised XCode didn't throw an error.

Is this a known XCode issue that I need to move the build artifacts directory if I move my project?

Answer (score 0):

I figured it was tied to this project being created by XCode 3 and this setting was causing it.

It should be `Xcode Default`. However now I'm getting, previously unseen, linker errors.

[image]